# Can't install package 'nutshell' from O'Reilly book 'R in a Nutshell' onto Mac

Tags: r, statistics, package

My first post in an early programming career - any help very welcome.

I am studying R, and using a book called R in  Nutshell (O'Reilly). The book is supported by a package that was previously available on CRAN. The package on CRAN has been archived - it is still there though as nutshell_2.0.tar.gz.

I am running MacOS Catalina, R version 3.2.1.(after downgrading from 4.02 to try and solve this issue , without success), and RStudio version 1.3.1093.

When I try to install the package into R via RStudio I have this experience:

```
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/nutshell/nutshell_2.0.tar.gz
install.packages(packageurl,contriburl=NULL,type="source")

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/nutshell/nutshell_2.0.tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
```

I have a similar experience if I download the tar.gz file and try to import it directly under Tools/Install Packages.

I am able to install other packages on CRAN successfully.

Many thanks

Comment: I *strongly* urge you to use a version of R more modern than 3.2.1. It was released in Dec 2015, the next minor (not patch) upgrade, R-3.3.0, was released in Apr 2016, and there have been several (not-insignificant) changes since then. R-3.6 was released in Apr 2019 and is still well-supported.

Comment: Did you check if you are trying to install the dependencies, or the route where it's trying to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up front, I'm doing this on *windows* and not on macos, but the packages here have no compiled code so there should be few if any differences. Also, I tested on R-4.0.2; I don't *think* this will be a problem, because these packages appear to have been last-updated in 2012, so if they install on my 4.0.2, then they are likely to work on every version of R since then (including your 4+ year-old R-3.2).

```r
download.file("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/nutshell.audioscrobbler/nutshell.audioscrobbler_1.0.tar.gz", "nutshell.audioscrobbler_1.0.tar.gz")
download.file("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/nutshell.bbdb/nutshell.bbdb_1.0.tar.gz", "nutshell.bbdb_1.0.tar.gz")
download.file("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/nutshell/nutshell_2.0.tar.gz", "nutshell_2.0.tar.gz")

install.packages("nutshell.audioscrobbler_1.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
install.packages("nutshell.bbdb_1.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
install.packages("nutshell_2.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing installation from archive. I got error that dependencies of this package are not available.

```
ERROR: dependencies 'nutshell.bbdb', 'nutshell.audioscrobbler' are not available for package 'nutshell'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library/nutshell'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘D:/Profile/maszpa1/Desktop/nutshell_2.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Did you get the same error? If yes, then did you try to install them and try again?

Answer (score 0):

As per the accepted answer, the solution was to install the missing dependent packages first, then the Nutshell package.

I was then able to update to R4.02

```
audioscrobbler_1.0.tar.gz
nutshell.bbdb_1.0.tar.gz
nutshell_2.0.tar.gz
```